# Как извлечь данные из Excel не открывая файл?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

ВОПРОС
Как извлечь данные из Excel не открывая файл?
Т.е., чтобы файл находился в закрытом положении, а данные извлекались и отображались в диалоговом окне.

СЦЕНАРИЙ 
1. В поле "ID" вводим значение "ID" (ID - записи восьмизначное число)
2. В поле "СОДЕРЖАНИЕ ЗАПИСИ" появляется запись из базы данных, которое соответствует ID.

Скриншот http://prntscr.com/caelb1

Прилагаю болванку для кода

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExcelDb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void groupBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ.
1. Проект
   [http://файлообменник.рф/x1mnp7qjtz61.html](http://%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84/x1mnp7qjtz61.html)

---

К ответу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559681:

1. Проект называется "ExcelDb";
2. Скачал файл "ClosedXML";
3. Разместил файлы по следующим путям;
    c:\ExcelDb\bin\Debug\ClosedXML.dll;
    c:\ExcelDb\bin\Debug\ClosedXML.XML;
4. Прописал в проекте 
   см. скриншот (https://yadi.sk/i/ur5Uuk5auYHt2);
5. Запускаю оладку;
6. Выдаёт ошибку;

ВОПРОС

1. Всё ли правиьлно сделал?
2. Не могли бы целиком код привести?
   у меня мало опыта.

Comment: Файл открывать все равно придётся, а вот окно самого excel можно и не показывать. Ну и как альтернатива, используйте сохранение из excel в csv. С последним можно работать как с текстом, если это возможно конечно.

Comment: Excel я условно принял.
В чём необходимо хранить базу данных, чтобы не открывать источник?

Comment: @koverflow Такое чувство, что Вы вкладываете какой-то свой смысл во фразу "открыть файл".

Comment: Я только осваиваю, поэтому могу некорректно формулировать. "открыть файл" - имею ввиду открыть файл (запустить). Как новичок, другого смысла в эту фразу не вкладываю. Через Ctrl+O открываем диалог и находим файл и открываем

Comment: Если вам вместо БД на первое время, то храните в CSV, такие файлы excel тоже прекрасно открывает и редактирует. Если не хотите мучиться с ручным парсингом, то посмотрите вариант XML, легко редактировать в любом текстовом редакторе, легко работать с помощью `XDocument` и сопутствующих классов. Вы бы описали в вопросе задачу которую решить пытаетесь. Под вопросом есть кнопка `править`, воспользуйтесь ей для редактирования

Comment: Вопрос скорректировал. Правда не знаю как более развёрнуто можно его описать.. Для наглядности прилагаю скриншот http://prntscr.com/caelb1. В скриншоте правда, Ексель открыт. Нужно сделать как показано на скриншоте,  но при закрытом файле Ексель. Если для начала сделать в Ексель с "а вот окно самого excel можно и не показывать". Потому как основная работа ведётся в Ексель ине хочется морочиться с импортом(экспортом)... Не знаю удалось ли описать проблему, так что прошу извинить. Задач вроде не сложная.

Comment: @koverflow - Вам следует воспользоваться одной из существующих библиотек для работы с Excel'ом: http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10992391/5796587

Comment: @koverflow если ваш вопрос "в чём необходимо хранить базу данных", то об этом и спрашивайте. Открыть файл вообще - далеко не то же самое, что "открыть файл в экселе". Любая программа будет должна открыть файл, чтобы прочитать его содержимое.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = @"D:\Книга1.xlsx"; // путь к Excel файлу
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(FileName);
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    int id = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(worksheet.Cell(id, 2).Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: 0. Проект называется "ExcelDb";
1. Скачал файл "ClosedXML";       
2. Разместил файлы по следующим путям;
     c:\ExcelDb\bin\Debug\ClosedXML.dll;
     c:\ExcelDb\bin\Debug\ClosedXML.XML;
3. Прописал в проекте 
   см. скриншот (https://yadi.sk/i/ur5Uuk5auYHt2);

4. Запускаю оладку;
5. Выдаёт ошибку;

ВОПРОС
1. Всё ли правиьлно сделал?
2. Не могли бы целиком код привести?
у меня мало опыта.

Cпасибо

Comment: Достаточно только файла `ClosedXML.dll`. Это и есть полный код, добавил `using ClosedXML.Excel`, событие на клик и всё работает. А ошибка то какая, которая на скриншоте?

Comment: " А ошибка то какая, которая на скриншоте?".  Да. Ошибка показана на скриншоте.

Comment: Ну так ошибка в строке 34, всё вроде написано как её исправить. И насколько я понимаю она не связана с ClosedXML.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы Вам не использовать EPPlus библиотеку. Также используйте шаблонные решения из документации там же.

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличный проект [Общие сведения о форматах файлов Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg278325.aspx)

[Как мне… (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb491088.aspx)

Очень удобно использовать Productivity Tool", она умеет генерировать код [Генерируем OfficeOpenXML-документы за 5 минут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/109820/)

Недавно написал статью, правда на 1С
[1С, Linux, Excel, Word, OpenXML,ADO и Net Core](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308216/)

В любом случае полесно ознакомиться.

Кроме того вот ссылки на стили https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116176/cell-styles-in-openxml-spreadsheet-spreadsheetml

Comment: Вам не сложно будет привести наиболее оптимальное решение для моих задач на примере моего проекта?